# An identity in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that 
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k=\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}(A_k-A_{k+1})\right)
\cup(A_n-A_1)\cup(A_1\cap A_2\cdots\cap A_n).$$
 Really, I did do it through taking element for two sides.  Is there any other method ?

How do you do it?

Comment: Ultimately taking elements is the basis.  If you know A U B = (A-B) U (B - A) U (A $\cap $ B) you can show this inductively.  But to get the first result one should take elements.  Or hope the definitions of union, intersection and exclusion make this self evident.  But as the definitions are about elements I don't think we can/should avoid elements.